# Оператор + невозможно применить к оператору типа "string" и "группа методов"

Tags: c#, строки, переменные, int

```
X1.ToString + "-y" + Y1.ToString + "-s" + Nickname.Text + "-i" + Image.Text
```

Хочю вывести текст в котором есть цыфры, но они перемнаживаются. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string.concat

Comment: потому что ToString - метод и вызывать его надо как `ToString()`, у вас скобочек нет

Comment: Я думаю если вы дочитаете до конца - сможете увидеть там примеры использования...

Comment: какой текст? Приведите пример. Какие цифры перемножаются? Покажите что и как вы делаете и какой вывод ожидаете

Comment: `fastColoredTextBox1.Text += $"\nBB.exe run -x {X1} -y {Y1} -s {Nickname.Text} -i {Image.Text} --notificationMode browser --placingOrder {Style.Text}";`

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы вызвать метод без аргументов, помимо его названия нужно написать круглые скобки:

```
"-x" + X1.ToString() + "-y" + Y1.ToString() + "-s" + Nickname.Text + "-i" + Image.Text
```

А вообще, это можно записать куда лаконичнее:

```
$"-x{X1}-y{Y1}-s{Nickname.Text}-i{Image.Text}"
```

- [Интерполяция строк](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation)

Comment: Ну так выводите отдельно, в чём проблема? Вы не указали в вопросе, что хотите получить, только сказали про ошибку с ToString. Обновите вопрос, добавив что ожидаете на выводе и я вам постараюсь помочь